Inconsistent output in the console when closing the express server
I am writing a Node/Express web application as part of my university module. At the moment, the application is very simple and I have three files: db.js, app.js, and entry.js.
The db.js module creates Sequelize instance and exports it so it's available to other modules. This is the entire code within db.js:
const { Sequelize } = require('sequelize');
const dbConfig = require('./dbconfig');

// Create Sequelize instance
const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV.trim();
const sequelize = new Sequelize(dbConfig\[NODE_ENV\]);

module.exports = sequelize;

The app.js imports the express module, creates an express application and exports it:
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
module.exports = app;

The entry.js is run by npm run devstart from the terminal (cmd, Windows). It runs SET NODE_ENV=dev && nodemon ./app/bin/entry.js script within package.json.
I want to gracefully handle the closure of server and sequelize instances, so my entry.js looks like this:
const sequelize = require('../../db/db');
const app = require('../app');

const port = 3000;

// Test database connection
const testDatabaseConnection = async () => {
    try {
        await sequelize.authenticate();
        console.log('Database connection successfull.');
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', error);
        throw(error);
    }
}

// Attempt to start the server
const serverStart = async () => {
    try {
        await testDatabaseConnection();
        const server = app.listen( port, () => {
            console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}.`);
        });
        return server;
    } catch(error) {
        console.error('Failed to start server:', error);
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

serverStart().then( (server) => {
    // Listen for process termination signals
    process.on('SIGINT', () => gracefulShutdown(server));
    process.on('SIGTERM', () => gracefulShutdown(server));
} );

// Gracefully close the application
const gracefulShutdown = async (server) => {
    
    console.log('Server is shutting down.');

    try {
        await new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
            server.close( (error) => (error ? reject(error) : resolve()) );
        } );
        await sequelize.close();
        console.log('Database connection closed successfully.');

        process.exit(0);

    } catch(error) {
        console.error('Error during shutdown:', error);
        process.exit(1);
    }
};

When I start and terminate the nodemon process with Ctrl + c in the terminal (cmd, Windows), I sometimes get this output:
Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result
Database connection successful.
Server listening on port 3000.
Server is shutting down.
^C^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)?

But, I am expecting it to be this:
Executing (default): SELECT 1+1 AS result
Database connection successful.
Server listening on port 3000.
Server is shutting down.
Database connection closed successfully.
^C^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)?

I am not sure why this happens. When I replace the nodemon with node in package.json script, the output seems to be consistent and I don't get this issue.
I apologise if the question is too long.
Any input or feedback is greatly appreciated.
Many thanks.

when you run your app with nodemon its wraps your application and manage the processes for you . the nodemon works based on the SIGIN and SIGTERM
enter link description here this is how the nodemon handle the gracefully shutdown . when use use CTL+C the signals that nodemon rely on it not transfered to your application so this situaion occured
this config may be solve you issue. in your nodemon.json add or change this :
{
"signal" : "SIGINT"
}

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

This may not be a concern when the app in production, since nodemon does not require there - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67719335/do-i-need-nodemon-in-production.
